# PayPal Android Sdk Vault

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

My requirement is to store credit card details in Paypal vault using Android. 
I followed these link

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/

there is no mention on how to vault a credit using Android sdk. I think it can be done using their Rest API. How do I achieve this in Android?

Comment: you are able to generate access token ?

Answer (score 3):

You can store credit card in paypal using vault api Follow this steps

**Step 1: Generate Access Token By OAuth Token Request**

Try in postman

```
      Url :- https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

      Headers :- (Key,Value)

      1.(Accept , application/json)
      2.(Accept-Language , en_US)
      3.(Content-Type , application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
      4.(Authorization , Basic<Space>(here your code generated by postman))
```

**Note :- Generate a Basic Auth in post man by select authorization tab ==> Basic Auth and enter paypal Client secret and Client id.**

```
      Body :- (Key,Value)
      1.(grant_type,client_credentials)
```

**Note :- Select x-www-form-urlencoded in body tab in postman**

**Step 2: Store credit card using valut api**
Try in postman

```
      Url :- https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-cards

      Headers :- (Key,Value)

      1.(Accept , application/json)
      2.(Accept-Language , en_US)
      3.(Content-Type , application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
      4.(Authorization , Bearer(your Access Token))

      Body : (Json)

{
  "payer_id": "user12345",
  "type": "visa",
  "number": "4111111111111111",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2018",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper",
  "billing_address": {
    "line1": "52 N Main ST",
    "city": "Johnstown",
    "state": "OH",
    "postal_code": "43210",
    "country_code": "US"
  }
}
```

**Note :- Select raw tab in body in postman.**

Comment: I successfully did this using postman.How do I do this in Android?

Comment: I already did this using postman.How do I make these api calls in Android?

Comment: @karanvs which network library you are using currently ?

Comment: Are you asking library for paypal ?

Comment: I am using Retrofit and currently following this, https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit

Comment: you tried this in retrofit than where problem is occurs ?@karanvs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123426/discussion-between-karan-vs-and-vishal-patoliya-).

Comment: Did't get luck for me. Its give me INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299782/not-able-to-store-credit-card-in-paypal-using-v1-vault-credit-cards

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to vishal for his help. I was able to solve this using retrofit (adding headers statically).

**1. First get the value of your authorization header:**

```
    String clientId = "your client id";
    String clientSecret = "your client secret";
    String credentials = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
    String basic =
            "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Log.e("Authorization",basic);
```

Copy this value from log, it will be used later in our solution.

**2. Make the response model according to this json:**

```
 {
  "scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
  "access_token":"Access-Token",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "app_id":"APP-6XR95014SS315863X",
   "expires_in":28800
 }
```

**3. Make retorfit call method as this:**

```
    @Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Accept-Language : en_US",
        "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization:your basic string value here"
        })
    @POST("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/")
    Call<AuthenticationTokenModel> getAuthentionToken(@Query("grant_type") String grant_type);
```

**4. Finally make the call as:**

```
     ApiInterface apiInterface= ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    apiInterface.getAuthentionToken("client_credentials").enqueue(new Callback<AuthenticationTokenModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AuthenticationTokenModel> call, Response<AuthenticationTokenModel> response) {
            Log.e("response",response.body().getAccess_token());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AuthenticationTokenModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("response",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Edited:

You can also add dynamic headers to requests in Retrofit 2.

Follow this:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header