# How to call Vault Pay Pal Api in android

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, credit-card

Hi I am looking to call vault pay pal api in android and I came across few links which is showing same problem I am facing.Can anyone help me to call Vault Pay Pal api in android to save credit card details so that user do not have to enter this details again and again while making payment.

Here are links I followed:

[PayPal Android Sdk Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508896/paypal-android-sdk-vault)

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can call vault pay pal api using retrofit library and following the steps mentioned in below two links of pay pal.First we have to call the first restful pay pal api to get access token.Once we get this access token we can call the vault api of pay pal to store credit card.Below are links for pay pal restful api:

1) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

2) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/vault/